# Exit from SSH sessions automatically without exiting script in python

Tags: python, unix, ssh, redhat

I have a task where I have to SSH to different unix servers to run some command and get output of each server in one single file. The script is in python 2 as follows-

```
import subprocess
server_list = ['server1', 'server2', 'server3']
for srv in server_list:
    subprocess.call(['ssh', srv])
    # DO PROCESS
```

The problem is that when I run the script from command line on server **myserver**, it ssh to **server1** and remains there until I manually run exit on command line. Then it goes to **server2**, again it remains there and I have to run exit. This process goes on until I return to **myserver**.
Unless I run the final exit, the file is not completed. So, I tried to give "exit" as command using subprocess module (to automate whole process), as follows

```
import subprocess
server_list = ['server1', 'server2', 'server3']
for srv in server_list:
    subprocess.call(['ssh', srv])
    # DO PROCESS
    subprocess.call(['exit'])
```

When I run this, It ssh to **'server1'**, again it does not return to **myserver**. When I run exit, I get error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_return_ssh.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['exit'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

And the execution stops.

What should I do to make this script work? I want to automate the whole process - ssh into servers, run the command and then after execution of whole script, exit and return to **myserver**.

I also have searched for this, but no link seems to provide the answer.

Comment: Do you only want to execute a single command on the remote server? In that case you can give it as a parameter to ssh: `ssh server1 echo This is executed on the server`. SSH will then exit after this command finished.

Comment: you can use pxssh (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/ssh-connection-with-python) to execute commands on remote machines, is there any need specific need that you want to use subprocess?  another thing is that `subprocess.call(['ssh', srv])` this will open sub process and run ssh command but you won't be having handle to that console to run another command on same prompt.

Comment: @L3viathan It is a piped command, something like `df -h | grep '\d+\%.+'`. Will this work?

Comment: @Mahesh Karia There is no specific need to use subprocess.

Comment: @AnkitSeth What you can definitely do is `ssh server df -h | grep ...`, which will pipe the output through your local grep. Doing it all remotely should also work, put it all in quotes.

Comment: I got it. I used **parallel-ssh** library and it did the work. Thanks everyone.